# Android custom notification is empty

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have been trying to build a custom notification.

Unfortunatly the notification juste comes out empty. I don't understand how is this possible, there are no errors the notificaiton is just white with 2 icons but no text.

I have tried on API 23 and 24, same things on both. Here is a print screen of the result:

[image]

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        showPreviousView();
    }
}

 public void customNotification() {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.custom_notification);

        String strtitle = getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle);
        String strtext = getString(R.string.customnotificationtext);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);
        intent.putExtra("text", strtext);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play)
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.customnotificationticker))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setContent(remoteViews);

        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotileft,R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotiright,R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle));
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,getString(R.string.customnotificationtext));

        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
```

**String.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">The Music Player</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_browse">Browser</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="notificationtitle">Android Notification Tutorial</string>
    <string name="notificationtext">Notification Text</string>
    <string name="notificationticker">Notification Ticker</string>
    <string name="customnotificationtitle">Android Notification Tutorial</string>
    <string name="customnotificationtext">Custom Notification Text</string>
    <string name="customnotificationticker">Custom Notification Ticker</string>
    <string name="lbltitle">"Title : "</string>
    <string name="lbltext">"Text : "</string>
    <string name="notification">Notification</string>
    <string name="customnotification">Custom Notification</string>
</resources>
```

**custom_notification.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenotileft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagenotileft"
        android:text="dayme son"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagenotileft" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenotiright"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***EDIT***

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void customNotification() {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.custom_notification);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", "title");
        intent.putExtra("text", "txt");
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play)
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.customnotificationticker))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setContent(remoteViews);


        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotileft,R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotiright,R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);

        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
```

**custom_notification**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenotileft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagenotileft"
    android:text="same text"
    android:textColor="#00FFFF"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagenotileft"
    android:text="this ia text"
    android:textColor="#00FFFF"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenotiright"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="this is a try"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notification text is not empty, it's just white so you dont see the it :)

Here is screenshot with a bit changed saturation/exposure/contrast,  try looking at your screen from different angle.

[image]

It clearly says:

```
Android Notification Tutorial
Custom Notification Text
```

Try changing the font color, eg. put in your xml:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

Comment: Wow, strong eyes ;)

Comment: I edtied my post and my code but i still get the result. I tried to change the color the text and add a button.

Comment: I suspect the `RemoteView` may be standing in the way. Can you try using `setTextColor(..., ...)` and `setTextViewText(..., ...)` methods of RemoteView right where you are setting image resources?